# Laravel takes server IP to load files and link URLs instead of accessing the requested URL

Tags: php, url, laravel, laravel-4, ip

My Laravel site is hosted on a IP to which I am redirecting a URL. The problem is that index page loads but all the css, js and images are being loaded from the IP and not the URL. Even all the internal links are going to that IP. 
Is laravel creating URLS based only on host IP instead of taking Request URL into acount.

Eg: Suppose my host IP for website is 1.2.3.4/xyz and my URL to access it is sub.abc.com/xyz
Then If I load sub.abc.com/xyz page opens but the js css and images are coming from 1.2.3.4/xyz instead of sub.abc.com/xyz 
And links are going to 1.2.3.4/xyz/contact instead of abc.com/xyz/contact

I am using laravel's methods to make these URLs

Note: xyz folder is being proxypassed to another ip

Comment: Have you tried to change the "hostname" in the bootstrap/start.php $app->detectEnvironment call ?

Comment: Yes I did all that but that was not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok from Laravel IRC chat I got to know that problem is something with the server configuration.

Thinking over all the configuration I guess this is what happening and causing problem

We type sub.abc.com/xyz which should go to abc.com-->sub-->xyz folder
So now Request URL is sub.abc.com/xyz

But in this folder there are no website files instead a Request(proxypassed) is made to another location 1.2.3.4/xyz which should look for a folder xyz on 1.2.3.4 So  now the Request URL becomes 1.2.3.4/xyz

So now when it comes to Laravel at 1.2.3.4/xyz, the Request URL is 1.2.3.4/xyz and not  sub.abc.com/xyz so all the files and links from laravel are returned with a URL of 1.2.3.4/xyz

Hence now the page that comes to the browser has 1.2.3.4/xyz links instead of requested sub.abc.com/xyz 
Now you may say that if whatever I said is true then why dont domain and corresponding IP breaks in all websites.

For which I will say that

Lets say you type xyz.com which points to 4.5.6.7 IP. 
here again website gets request URL as 4.5.6.7 and sends the file at same link
But then again this IP 4.5.6.7 is mapped back to xyz.com and served to browser so brwser gets correct link.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ProxyPreserveHost On` with your Apache virtual host ProxyPass directives.